# Average-Function of Sensor-Data in Android

Tags: android, math, average, android-sensors

I'm trying to build the weighted-average from the sensor-data I get by the SensorManager.
My problem is, that bearing, pitch and roll have a maximum value and when I'm exactly at this point, the values swap from 0 to 359 or backwards. 
My average is at the moment simply an addition of all values and one division by the number of values.

Let's say I get the values: 1, 359, 350, 10
In this case, I want to have an average of 0. How do I have to change my equation to get this functionality?

Do I have to check for the "nearest" distance to 0/360 and using this value instead of the real value?

This would also make some troubles if I have values around 180:

160, 200 -> the average has to be 180, but with my nearest-distance idea, it would be 160, because 200 + 160 = 360.

How can I solve this?

Edit: This are the values I get from the SensorManager.

- 0 <= azimuth<360
- 180<=pitch<=180
- 90<=roll<=90

Edit2: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I'm using a weighted average:

```
double sum = 0;
for int i = 0; i < max; i++
   sum += value[i] * (i / (triangular_number(max))
return sum
```

Comment: In your algorithm try and add all the `azimuth` and see if they are an integral multiple of 360. If it is so, then you can keep the value to be 0 as you wanted. I can see this as one pattern which you can take the leverage of.

Comment: Hey, I think you got my question wrong ;) I'm not looking for a modular function, my problem is the average of values like 350, 10, 330, 30, which should be zero, but mathematically, its around 180

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To calculate average of angle use the following

```
public static final float averageAngle(float[] terms, int totalTerm)
{
    float sumSin = 0;
    float sumCos = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < totalTerm; i++)
    {
        sumSin += Math.sin(terms[i]);
        sumCos += Math.cos(terms[i]);
    }
    return (float) Math.atan2(sumSin / totalTerm, sumCos / totalTerm);
}
```

Comment: Hey. Thanks! Torben already mentioned this formula. But how can I implement a weighted average with this? where do I have to multiplicate the value with my weight?

Comment: Why do you want weighted average?

Comment: I'm just testing some different methods ;) and because usually "newer is better", i want to put a weight into my formula

Comment: You have to put your weight on the angle before calculating the average.

Comment: so you mean like: `sumSin += Math.sin(terms[i] * weight)` ? I did this, but I don't get any good value from it. atan2((sin(x*0.4) + sin(x*0,6)), (cos(x*0.4) + cos(x*0.6))) should return x because the value didn't change, but it doesn't.

Comment: sin(x*0.4) + sin(x*0,6) is not sin(x) so atan2 above is not x.

Comment: Hm, I don't know how to handle this. Can you give me a hint?

Comment: atan2(sin(300) + sin(300), cos(300)+ cos(300)) = -60 = 300 , hm... you meant "before calculating the average", where in your formula you mentione, do I have to use it? I thought my guess was correct :/

Comment: I need to know the reason you want to do weighted average before I am able to suggest what to do. Instead of the angle you can average the rotation matrices and then calculate the angles using getOrientation. In this case it is just the regular average.

Comment: The reason is the fact, that newer values usually are more accurate than older values, so I just want to have a little bit from "old" values, but in general, I want to have the newest value. It's just for testing which methods of sensor-data-smoothing are the most useful for my application where I project something on my display which depends on my bearing ;)

Comment: In that case make the newer count as multiple times. For example if a newer angle is 1.5 make it count multiple times 1.5, 1.5, 1.5 (for example 3 times)

Comment: Oh my gosh... simple but awesome! Thank you very much :))

Answer (score 1):

I found a [blog post](http://positivelyglorious.com/software-media/averages-of-azimuths/) about this.

To summarize it shortly: You have to calculate the average of the sines of all your aizmuth values and the average of the cosines of the aizmuth values and then put these average values in the atan2 function, then if necessary make the result positive by adding 2 * PI. Don't forget to convert degrees values to radians and vice versa.

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible, to use a weighted average function on it? I forgot to mention that It has to be weighted (value * (index/size)). Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think it should work with a weighted average as well. The average i mentioned is an arithmetic average, so you could just try to use a weighted arithmetic average instead.

Comment: HM I don't get any "good" results when I'm trying to combine it with weight... This is where I added the weight-function: sumSin += Math.sin(bearing)* (weight); same with cos, and then at the end atan2(sin,cos). Or do I have to put the weight-calculation at another place?

Comment: This should be correct. Did you divide by the sum of the weights?